# Finding the maximum value between two columns where one of them is shifted and change the value of last row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
       'a': [20, 9, 31, 40],
       'b': [1, 10, 17, 30],
    }
)
```

Expected output: Creating column `c` and `name`

```
    a   b   c    name
0  20   1  20    NaN
1   9  10  20    NaN
2  31  17  17    NaN
3  40  30  40    a
```

Steps:

a) `c` is created by `df['c'] = np.fmax(df['a'].shift().bfill(), df['b'])`

b) for the last row: `df['c'] = df[['a', 'b']].max()`. Since for the last row `a > b` 40 is chosen.

c) Get the name of max value between `a` or `b` for the last row.

My attempt:

```
df['c'] = np.fmax(df['a'].shift().bfill(), df['b'])
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'c'] = df.loc[df.index[-1], ['a', 'b']].max()
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'name'] = df.loc[df.index[-1], ['a', 'b']].idxmax()
```

Is it the cleanest way / best approach?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand... why does it matters where column `c` is coming from? Isn't the real question how to get the name of the column with the max between `a` and `b`, independently of `c`?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly It was my previous question on SO. I wanted to know maybe there are other ways to create `c` on the spot. Without using first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't how much of an improvement it is but you can combine the last two lines of code into a single single line if you use `agg()`.

```py
df['c'] = np.fmax(df['a'].shift().bfill(), df['b'])
idx = df.index[-1]
df.loc[idx, ['c', 'name']] = df.loc[idx, ['a', 'b']].agg(['max', 'idxmax']).to_numpy()
```

To create a copy, we could define a mask that flags the last row and `assign()` "c" and "name" columns.

```py
msk = df.index == df.index[-1]
df1 = df.assign(
    c=np.fmax(df['a'].shift().bfill().mask(msk, df['a']), df['b']), 
    name=df[['a', 'b']].idxmax(axis=1).where(msk)
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Which one does your instinct prefer? :)

Comment: @x_Amir_x I would probably define a separate variable for the index first (eg. `idx=df.index[-1]`) to use later in the assignment; otherwise I would prefer the code I've written lol.